# Python Socket Server Accept No Response

Tags: python, sockets, server

I am trying to connect to my linux server from a windows machine through python socket. However, the socket.accept() on server side doesn't seems to be responsive to the client's connection.

Server:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8080))
s.listen()
print("listening...")
conn, address = s.accept()
print("Connection from " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
```

Client:

```
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((<my server ip>, 8080))
client_socket.send(bytes("hello", "utf-8"))
```

Expected behavior:
Server:

```
Listening...
Connection from <my local ip>:<local ip port>
```

Actual behavior:

```
Listening...
```

Other results:

1. `ping <my server ip>`  from local machine succeed.
2. Client code execute til the end without error.
3. `sudo lsof -ni tcp:8080` on the server list my process that's listening on port 8080.

What might go wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Please describe the exact behavior you expect and what you get instead, i.e. error messages, code behavior etc. Also note that *"... it seems like the connection is successful and some messages went through."* does not really make much sense - unless you accidentally connect to a different service. But again, please don't just interpret the results (and possibly in the wrong way) but show the actual details of what is happening. It might make sense to add some more debug output to your code to actually see what is happening though, i.e. especially if the `connect` of the client succeeded.

Comment: do you run it in the same network? Maybe client connect with different computer. If you connect from internet then you connect to router of your Internet Provider - and it would have to redirect it to your server (but usually Internet Providers block this access for your security) Often providers keep open ports like 80, 8000, 8080 and it is better use them instead ports like 30000. BTW: check what you get with `socket.gethostname()` - maybe it gets `127.0.0.0` and then it doesn't accept external connections. It is better to use `0.0.0.0` on server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you for your suggestion!   I added in more info in the description.    Do you have idea on how to debug the client_socket?    I called ```client_socket.getpeername()``` and it returns my server ip and port.

Comment: @furas thank your for your suggestion! ```socket.gethostname()``` gives me a string name but ```socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())``` returns 127.0.0.1 - why does it mean it won't accept external connections?    Is there way    I can reconfigure that?

Comment: Use `s.bind(('',8080))` on server.  The server will accept connections from any interface.

Comment: as I said - use `'0.0.0.0'` or empty `''` instead of `socket.gethostname()` - `s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080))`. Address `127.0.0.1` accepts connection only from local programs installed on the same computer as you run server. It can be used for security. You can run web page with `0.0.0.0` and everyone will access it - but this page can use `127.0.0.1` to access local database and others (hackers) will not have access to this database.

Comment: thank you @furas this solved my problem!
Does this means that if I want to be connected by a specific client I can put the client's address in?

Comment: no. `server` uses IP of network card which you have on this computer - and it listens clients on this card. IP `127.0.0.1` means virtual network card (called `"Loopback"`) which gives only access for local program. If computer has LAN card with local IP ie. `192.168.1.1` and you use this IP in server then it will accept only client which connect by LAN (but not local programs which use `127.0.0.1`). If you have WiFi with local IP. ie. `10.0.0.1` and you use this IP in server then it wil accept only client fro WiFi. And `0.0.0.0` accept client from all network cards - LAN, WiFi, Loopback.